# How do I spawn a separate python process?

Tags: python, subprocess, spawn

I need to spawn a separate python process that runs a sub script.

For example:

main.py runs and prints some output to the console. It then spawns sub.py which starts a new process. Once main.py has spawned sub.py it should terminate whilst sub.py continues to run.

Thank you.

Edit:

When I run main.py it prints 'main.py' but nothing else and sub.py doesn't launch.

main.py

```
print "main.py"

import subprocess as sp
process=sp.Popen('sub.py', shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate(exexfile('sub.py'))  # The output and error streams

raw_input("Press any key to end.")
```

sub.py

```
print "sub.py"
raw_input("Press any key to end.")
```

Comment: What operating system you are on? Do you launch `main.py` from some ide?

Answer (score 4):

#### execfile

The straightforward approach:

```
execfile('main.py')
```

#### Subprocess

Offers fine-grained control over input and output, can run processes in background:

```
import subprocess as sp
process=sp.Popen('other_file.py', shell=True, stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate()  # The output and error streams.
```

Comment: You need to enter data to the `communicate` method. Will edit my answer soon.

Comment: Thanks. I've added `exexfile('sub.py')` to the `communicate()` method, and now it runs the sub.py file, but in the same console so how do you get it to run seperately? I'm probably missing something really simple, sorry. Thanks again.

Comment: >> Once main.py has spawned sub.py it should terminate whilst sub.py continues to run.