# How to give Python requests headers to apply_async?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm working on parallel GET functionality with apply_async as described in [Python Requests: Don't wait for request to finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27021440). My problem is that I need to supply headers to every GET request and I fail to figure out how to do that.

I'm trying along these lines:

```
items.append(pool.apply_async(requests.get, [url, "", {"header1":"value1", "header2":"value2"}]))
```

and many variations of the theme without success.

I would appreciate information how to work my way through this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [the requests docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#custom-headers), you need to pass headers in the `headers` keyword argument to `requests.get`.

According to [the multiprocessing docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.apply_async), the arguments to `apply_async` are:

```
apply_async(func, args=(), kwds={}, callback=None)
```

Which in your case would translate to:

```
pool.apply_async(requests.get, 
                 [url], 
                 dict(headers={"header1":"value1", "header2":"value2"}))
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried {headers:{... but it did not work. This dict(headers={... works.

Comment: Well, `dict(headers={...})` produces the same result as `{'headers': {...}}`, so I'm not sure that was the problem, but I'm glad things are working!